# How to determine the real disk size of an hardware RAID?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid-controller

I have a Fujitsu Primergy TX200 S3 server running Win Server 2003 R2 SP2. 
It has hardware-RAID using an LSI Logic MegaRAID SAS 8300XLP RAID Controller.

I simply want to find the size of each disk in the RAID array. How can I find this information?

Update: I should have mentioned that the RAID manager tool is not working for me right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sarcastic bit of me wants to say "pop the case and read the label", but I'm making a real effort to be more helpful today...

I'm a Linux bloke for the most part, so I'm not *entirely* sure, but the "MegaRAID Storage Manager - Windows" on [this support page from LSI](http://www.lsi.com/support/products/Pages/MegaRAID%20SAS%208300XLP.aspx) should be able to tell you the size of the RAID array components.  Certainly the Linux equivalent tool can do it, so I'd be stunned if the info wasn't available in the Windows tool.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find it in the administrative software for that RAID. It is either in the software provided by LSI or in the controller's BIOS while boot-up.

In normal situations a hardware RAID is designed to hide the real disk sizes from the OS and only presenting the RAIDed "virtual" hard disk.